# Complex filtering based on a many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application, `Annotations` are considered "accepted" if **either**:

1. They have been explicitly marked "accepted" (i.e., their state == 'accepted')
2. They were last updated by a user who has the "editor" role

My question is how to find all accepted explanations with a single DB query. Basically I'm looking for the database-driven version of

```
Annotation.all.select do |a|
  a.last_updated_by.roles.map(&:name).include?('editor') or a.state == 'accepted'
end
```

My first attempt was

```
Annotation.all(:joins => {:last_updated_by => :roles}, :conditions => ['roles.name = ? or annotations.state = ?', 'editor', 'accepted'])
```

But this returns a bunch of duplicate records (adding a `.uniq` makes it work though)

Changing `:joins` to `:include` works, but this makes the query way too slow

Answer (score 1):

Are the results of your first attempt just wrong or do they only need an ".uniq"?
Have you tried

```
:include => {:last_updated_by => [:roles]}
```

instead of the join?

or making two queries

```
@ids = Editor.all(:conditions => ["role = 'editor'"], :select => ["id"]).map{|e|e.id}
Annotation.all(:conditions => ["last_updated_by in (?) or state = ?", @ids.join(","), "accepted"]
```

is that any faster?

Comment: how big are your tables and are you using indices?

Comment: otherwise two queries maybe a lot faster